# (Microsoft) SQL: grab data from a multiple columns conditionally

Tags: database, t-sql, join

I just started working with SQL. The data is stored as in three tables. An example is given below...

**TABLE1**: ProductFamily

```
column: product family
```

**TABLE2**: facility

```
column: location
```

**TABLE3**: strap

```
column: build plant
column: prod series
column: 2012 Full Units w/C
column: 2013 Full Units w/C
column: 2014 Full Units w/C
column: 2015 Full Units w/C
column: 2016 Full Units w/C
column: 2017 Full Units w/C
column: 2018 Full Units w/C
```

If... any text value stored in "location" matches a given text value in "building plant" & If any text value stored in "product family" matches a given text value in "product type"

then... grab the contents of the seven columns "201X Full Units w/C:" in the corresponding rows and build a new table consisting of them and their matched "location" and "product family" values.

MY QUERY:

```
select facility.location, ProductFamily.productfamily, strap.[2012 Full Units w/C], [2013 Full Units w/C],  strap.[2014 Full Units w/C],  strap.[2015 Full Units w/C], [2016 Full Units w/C], strap.[2017 Full Units w/C], strap.[2018 Full Units w/C]
from facility, ProductFamily
inner join strap on ProductFamily.productfamily = strap.[prod series]
inner join facility on strap.[build plant] = facility.location;
```

I'm not sure the query will accomplish what i want its also giving  a syntax error (missing operator)

Comment: Try changing `from facility, ProductFamily` to just `from ProductFamily` (leave the joins in place) - do you still get an error?

Comment: Yeah, I still have the error after the change

Comment: So my query also still gives the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
from facility, ProductFamily
```

I would write the query like this:

```
select F.location, P.productfamily, S.[2012 Full Units w/C],
    S.[2013 Full Units w/C],  S.[2014 Full Units w/C], S.[2015 Full Units w/C], 
    S.[2016 Full Units w/C], S.[2017 Full Units w/C], S.[2018 Full Units w/C]
from strap S
inner join ProductFamily P on S.[prod series] = P.productfamily
inner join facility F on S.[build plant] = F.location;
```

(I am not a big fan of spaces in table and column names)